# Change default settings in MacVim

Tags: vim, macvim, default-settings

I want to do some changes in MacVim to suit my needs. I'm new in it, so stick with me.

The basic changes I want to do is to start the program with the following settings:

Line numbers activated
Top toolbar deactivated
Auto-indenting activated

I found out that you can write set lines=xx columns=yy to the /Users/USERNAME/.gvimrc file and it will change the default window width-height Also, you can change the color scheme with :colorscheme scheme in that file, too, but I don't know how to change the other settings.

I wanna give Vim a try, but the little things (like these) are important.

Comment: im trying to follow this ..but I dont know if there IS a ~/.gvimrc file ... at least I dont have one... do I create one when I want to change settings like this? or am I doing something wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line numbers:

```
:set number
```

Top toolbar deactivated:

```
:set guioptions-=T
```

Auto-indenting activated:

```
:filetype indent on
```

Be aware that you can turn off the menu bar as well, see "`:help 'guioptions'`".

Also, you may want to do "`:filetype indent plugin on`" as well as "`:syntax on`".  See "`:help :filetype`".

Comment: Whether `:filetype indent on` is sufficient depends on what AeroCross means by "Auto-indenting". He probably wants to use `:set autoindent` as well to have that option enabled for files such as plain text and configuration files.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for (both post and comment). I just wanted to know though, where did you find those settings? I did a little research and I couldn't find those directives (such as guioptions).

Comment: @AeroCross: I suggest doing a raw ":help" and familiarizing yourself with how the help system works, including the notation for getting help on various things, such as using a single-quote at the beginning of option names.  The full reference on what options are available is in ":help options.txt".  A briefer quick-reference for options is available in ":help Q_op".

Comment: @AeroCross: There's also the Vim user's manual, available by doing ":help usr_toc.txt".

Comment: I didn't know any of that, thank you so much for the information. Vim really has a steep learning curve, and it's not too friendly at the beggining, so I'll need a LOT of patience for this to workout - and of couse, superuser.com and kind people like you.